# Text Wrap with a background-img

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

As shown in this screenshot, I'm trying to get my text to wrap so that it goes around the background-img.

[image]

Obviously this won't work all in itself, therefore I've come here to ask for a possible solution. There are a few ways I've thought of myself, such as putting the image there using absolute positioning, but I'm pretty sure it wouldn't help me wrap the text.

Comment: CSS http://pastebin.com/cWbbAUY2

Comment: Remember, when you are floating elements, then the element which is supposed to be `float:right` must be placed as first element in the html structure! :-)

Answer (score 5):

recently found just such a piece can help

[shape](http://razvancaliman.com/writing/css-shapes-editor-chrome/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class named TextWrap or whatever you choose with properties as follows:

```
.TextWrap  {
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Adjust the float/margin depending on where you want the image in relation to the text. Add the class as the name in your image in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery plugin for stuff like this:

http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/

Here what they say:

> Why would I need this?
>
> If you've ever felt the need to wrap stuff around an
>   irregularly-shaped image using CSS's float, you may have been somewhat
>   disappointed to find out that it's forced to wrap around the image's
>   bounding box, rather than the actual contents of the image.

UPD. And yet another one: http://baconforme.com/